# Seagate Backup Plus Slim 2TB External HDD has varying read/write speeds on different computers

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate Backup Plus Slim 2TB Portable External Hard Drive. I used this hard drive for around 2 years with no problems. Then one fine day, every media file on the hard drive would stutter during playback for some reason.
I was convinced that the problem was with the HDD, so I had it replaced.
I just got my replaced HDD yesterday, and unfortunately it is facing the same problem.

I did some digging. I ran Crystal Disk Mark test on the Seagate HDD on:

- My Laptop
- 2 Desktops

The problem seems to occur only when I'm using it with my Laptop. And it's really clear with Crystal Disk Mark test results too. I'm completely baffled and have no clue as to why something like this would happen.

I copied a 8.6 GB file from the PC (Internal HDD) to the Seagate HDD and it absolutely crushed it with a constant speed of around 130 MB/s.

When I copied a 10.9 GB file from the Laptop (Internal HDD) to the Seagate HDD, it would sometimes dip down to 355 KB/s and for the rest; vary between 20 MB/s to 50 MB/s.

I have tried all the ports on my laptop and the issue persists.
I tried copying the 10.9 GB file from my Laptop to a different external HDD, and it was working fine.

Also the media playback (of files on Seagate HDD) won't stutter at all on PC, while I cant go 15 seconds without the playback stuttering on my Laptop.

This is very strange, and I have conclued that the Laptop specifically isn't playing nice with the Seagate HDD.
This seems really unscientific to say the least, specially since my laptop is the more capable machine on paper.

Any clues?

Crystal Disk Mark Test Results on Laptop

[image: Crystal Disk Mark Test Results on Laptop]

Copying 10.9 GB file from Laptop to Seagate HDD

[image: Copying 10.9 GB file from Laptop to Seagate HDD]

=====================

Crystal Disk Mark Test Results on PC

[image: Crystal Disk Mark Test Results on PC]

Crystal Disk Mark Test Results on another PC

[image: Crystal Disk Mark Test Results on another PC]

Copying 8.6 GB file from PC to Seagate HDD

[image: Copying 8.6 GB file from PC to Seagate HDD]

Comment: Anyone? I really need an expert opinion on this.

Comment: Is this the usual response time to every question on this website?